# ROS Python msg, send list of ints

Tags: python, arrays, list, int, ros

I have a list with ints:

```
perc = [0, 70, 85, 13, 54, 60, 67, 26]
```

and I want to send this to another ROS node. I have the following .msg file:

```
#File name: emotion_percentage.msg
Header header
uint8 percentage
```

My publisher code:

```
obj = emotion_percentage()
obj.percentage = str(perc)
self.emo_pub.publish(obj)
```

My listener code:

```
def callback(self, emo_perc):
    print(emo_perc.percentage)
    print(type(emo_perc.percentage))
```

The type in the listener code says: (type 'str'), even when I remove str() in str(perc) from the publisher code. However if I remove str(), the output is gibberish.

From the ROS wiki (http://wiki.ros.org/msg) I got that 'string' is the right format for this.

### Question

So now I got a string in my listener node, but how do I convert this back to an list with ints? Is converting my list to a string really the right way?

### Wrong code

```
perc = [int(i) for i in emo_perc.percentage]
```

gives error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

map() also doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the actual content of your emo_perc.percentage.

Comment: if you listener always get string, can you consider json instead of list? I mean at least you can convert a stringified json into a real json easily, right?

Comment: @TanveerAlam emo_perc.percentage is the object made in the publisher node, so it contains the list of 'perc' as a string. (see agugliotta 's answer)

Comment: @JerryMeng it seems to me that using a javascript encoding to get this done is a bit of a roundabout way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only uint8 is seen as a string, so my problem would be solved with uint16[]:

```
Header header
uint16[] percentage
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using python 2.x, where the `str` type is an array of 8-bit unsigned integers. In python 2.x the `str` data type is used to transfer raw byte arrays, this is why you are getting a `str` back from the message. To convert a `str` to a list of ints you can do:

```
lst = list(array.array("B", data))
```

`"B"` tells the array that the data is in a format of 8-bit unsigned integers. The returned result from `array` is a list-like data type. The major difference being an array constrains what types of data can be set to it or added to it. For the most part an array will suffice, you can simply use `arr = array.array("B", data)`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
str(perc)
```

you are creating a string like this

```
'[0, 70, 85, 13, 54, 60, 67, 26]'
```

you need to remove the brackets(first and last character) and then split it with the "," as delimiter like this:

```
perc = [int(i) for i in emo_perc.percentage[1:-1].split(",")]
```

Output:

```
[0, 70, 85, 13, 54, 60, 67, 26]
```

Comment: Thanks this works! However is this really the right way to do it? I mean to cast it to a string and then perform a string operation just to send a list of integers?

Comment: If you cast it to String only for print the list then no, it has no sense to do that because you can print the list of int `In [20]: print([0, 70, 85, 13, 54, 60, 67, 26]) # => the result is [0, 70, 85, 13, 54, 60, 67, 26]`

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I meant sending this information from 1 ROS node to the other as a message type. It's strange you can't just send an array, but have to cast it to a string and back.

Comment: I have no experience with ROS but if I understand well, you have no other choice because you defined the **percentage** variable like a **uint8** in the file

Comment: This is not correct. His message still only supports a single uint8 value, not a list, so converting it to a list before assignment is irrelevant. The message class will fail during serialization until he fixes his definition.